# Java map in a map, REST web Service

Tags: java, json, rest, dictionary

//
Hello guys,

So I am making a inbox element, and.. I needed to get field "startDate" from service, but I faced a problem, because all data in this service is "deeply" maped..

what  I figured out, is :

```
GenericType<Map<String, Object>> responseType2 = new GenericType<Map<String, Object>>() {};   
Map<String, Object> data2 = info.readEntity(responseType2);

Map<String, Object> data3 = (Map<String, Object>) data2.get("data");

Map<String, Object> data4 = (Map<String, Object>) data3.get("workflowInstance");
```

And only after all this, I am able to get what I needed..

Ok, it works, but code looks very redundant ?!

And, what I am hoping to find is, a way to make something like map in a map, or any other way, to make code more efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your brief snippet of code exactly what you're trying to do, but assuming all you're after is a simple utility, you could write a method like this:

```
public static <T> Map<String, T> get(Map<String, ?> data, String... path)
{
  if (path.length == 0)
  {
    return null;
  }

  Map<String, ?> child = data;   

  for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
  {
    String childKey = path[i];
    child = child.get(childKey);

    if (child == null)
    {
      return null;
    }                
  }  

  return child;    
}
```

Which could be called like this:

```
Map<String, Object> data = get(info.readEntity(responseType2), "data", "workflowInstance");
```

This code isn't going to be more efficient in speed terms than individual `Map.get`s as shown in the question, but it's certain more readable, imho.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I couldn't explain good enought,  but what worked out great for me, is:

`GenericType<Map<String, List<WorkflowTask>>> responseType = new GenericType<Map<String, List<WorkflowTask>>>(){};
  Map<String, List<WorkflowTask>> data = response.readEntity(responseType);
  response.close();`